# How to collected data after a delimiter, following an email address in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, email

I'm writing a PHP script as a sort of learning project. When finished it will allow the user to paste a paragraph of text into an HTML form and it will extract all email addresses, and the persons name from the text and present them in a list.

So far I am able to extract the email addresses using the following:

```
$pre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pre']);     

//Regex to find email addresses
$email_pattern = '/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/i';    

//save email addresses in an array
preg_match_all($email_pattern, $pre, $email_matches); 

echo "<h1>Mailing list</h1>
<p>Here are the email addresses contained within the text and the recipients name</p>";

//display list showing each unique email address only once.    
foreach(array_unique($email_matches[0]) as $email) {    
echo $email."<br />";
}
```

In the particular text I'm using the email address is always followed by a comma, then a ' then the persons name eg:

*'example@example.com','john smith','example2@example2.com','Jane smith'...etc.*

My question is, for each email address, how can I save the persons name ideally in a separate array?

Is there a regex that can identify an email address, skip a certain number of characters then select the all content up until another character is detected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
$re = "/([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\\'\\,\\'([A-Za-z\\s]*)\\'/";
```

String:

```
$str = "'example@example.com','john smith','example2@example2.com','Jane smith','example@example.com','john smith','example2@example2.com','Jane smith','example@example.com','john smith','example2@example2.com','Jane smith'";
```

Find all matches:

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

`$matches` will be an array of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => example@example.com','john smith'
            [1] => example2@example2.com','Jane smith'
            [2] => example@example.com','john smith'
            [3] => example2@example2.com','Jane smith'
            [4] => example@example.com','john smith'
            [5] => example2@example2.com','Jane smith'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => example@example.com
            [1] => example2@example2.com
            [2] => example@example.com
            [3] => example2@example2.com
            [4] => example@example.com
            [5] => example2@example2.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => john smith
            [1] => Jane smith
            [2] => john smith
            [3] => Jane smith
            [4] => john smith
            [5] => Jane smith
        )

)
```

Which means that `$match[1][n]` will be the email address of `$match[2][n]`.